# Is it possible to use a an existing mock-server using pact-jvm and Junit5?

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

Is it possible to configure an existing Pact Mock Server using Pact Junit5 Consumer?

I know it is possible to write my own Pact Plugin just for that but it seems overkill.

I do not want the Junit Framework to create the Mock Server for me but I want to set it up myself.
Is this possible?

Thanks.

PS. is there a good community where I can ask Pact questions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do so, but the best community to ask questions is http://slack.pact.io :)